# Josephus problem extended

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose there are $2n$ people  in a circle; the first n are good guys and the last n are bad guys. If we go around the circle executing every $m$-th person, all the bad guys are first to go. How to find the smallest value $m$.

Comment: is $m=-1$ allowed?

Comment: @Michael $ m>0 $